# Read the file and then create a dynamic array

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the sum and the average of all numbers.
I am not getting any error or the right output.
Any help is appreciated

```
 #include <iostream>

 #include <fstream>

 #include <string>

 #include <iomanip>

 using namespace std;

 int main(){

    double temp;
    double total = 0.0;
    double avg;
    int counter = 0;

    ifstream file("dataFile.txt");
    while (file >> temp)
    {
    cout << temp << " " << endl;;
    ++counter;
    }
    cout << "Total number of elements: " << counter << endl;
    file.close();
    file.open("dataFile.txt");

    double *num = new double[counter]();

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    cin >> num[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    total += num[i];
    }
    avg = total / counter;

    cout << "\n\nTotal: " << total << endl;
    cout << "Average: " << avg << endl;
    delete[] num;
    num = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Related question: If all you want is the average, why use an array at all? Just keep pulling in values until the file is exhausted while bumping a counter, divide by count, there's your average. No array required. And one loop rather than three. More related: How do you know your file even opened successfully. You never checked that.

Comment: I am suppose to use dynamic array for this assignment. The first loop is to make sure file opens successfully, its not required.

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of `new[]` directly. Then you only need 1 loop that `push_back()` the values into the vector as they are being read from the file, then you can loop through the vector to total the sum (or use `std::accumulate()` without a loop) and divide it by the vector's `size()` to get the average. But in any case, why are you reading values from `std::cin` instead of `file` when filling the allocated array?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you so much. i just change cin >> num[i] to file >>num[i] it works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

I think your issue is that you iterated through the whole file to get the size of the input, but your position in the file when you re-open it is still at the end. Check out [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/30644/) to make it go back to the beginning before you re-open it.

Comment: "*your position in the file when you re-open it is still at the end*" - that is not how `open()` works. It always resets back to the beginning, unless you specify the `std::ios_base::ate` flag, which this code is not.